# What kind of database/storage does google keep chrome app use?

Tags: android, ios, html, google-chrome, windows-phone-7

Am looking to build an app that would function like google keep.
just a light brush of the features:

- Chrome app with offline storage - save online when internet is available
- Android app and ios that would sync with the web server and also update locally and online
  -single user

Am thinking that I would have a bridge(SERVER) of some sort to handle the imports and exports of data between different platforms. Thus emulate a sync.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: what kind of storage/database does the google keep chrome app possibly  use?
was checking out HTML5 WebDatabases... not sure if thats the best way to go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep uses IndexedDB as it is the standard datastore available to Chrome Apps.  You should be able to right-click on the screen and see the code (visit the Resources tab).

Chrome Apps also has [Synchronised Storage](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage.html) that will manage offline and cloud access to your data storage.  This means you can set a key on one machine the user has and see it updated immediately on the other machine of the user.  The problem is that if you as a developer want to access and manage this data you can't do it, which is why Keep chose to use IndexedDB and manage the synchronisation themselves.

Answer (score -1):

Ay used Index DB but it saves the content somewhere as indexdb only saves to the local computer. SO needs to be saved somewhere else.